# How to sort and remove items from list base on alphabetical?

Tags: python, list, alphabetical

My teacher is giving us an exercise problem on how to processing a list. I came across with sorting a list alphabetically, but he never taught us this before so I have no clue how to do things.

The problem is creating a loop that will output only the names that come before `"Thor"` in the alphabet from the `names` list. This is what I tried:

```
names = ["Peter", "Bruce", "Steve", "Tony", "Natasha", "Clint", "Wanda", "Hope",
         "Danny", "Carol"]
thor = []
index = 1
for i in names:
  if names <= "Thor":
    thor.append ()
  index +=1
print(thor)
```

Comment: Did you mean `if i <= "Thor"` and `.append(i)` ?

Comment: Omg, I was thinking so hard but I didnt think of that lol, I think I didnt think enough. Thank you so much!

Comment: Functional approach: `thor = list(filter(lambda x: x < 'Thor', names))`. BTW, do you see that you don't need `index` in your solution?

Comment: The list can check the next item in the list without the index?

Comment: You don't need the index. You don't use the value `index` anywhere to access the list. Did you get the idea that naming a variable `index` would turn it automatically into some kind of weird lis access thing? A list is iterable, so while processing the `for` loop `i` will be bound to one element after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Python is very well suited for this kind of thing.  `for` loops in Python, for example, do not need a numeric index to traverse a list.  So, for what you are trying to do, it could be as simple as:

```
names = ["Peter", "Bruce", "Steve", "Tony", "Natasha", "Clint", "Wanda", "Hope", "Danny", "Carol"]

# Go through the list of names one at a time
for one_name in names:
    # Check to see if the current name is "less than" Thor
    if one_name < "Thor":
        # If you found a name like that, print it out
        print(one_name)
```

Comment: That is way simpler than my code haha, thank you so much, I will try it out!